# Domain names for various local web sites

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I need to use a web site different to my local Default Web Site for some development work on Windows 7, IIS 7.5.  I have created a new web site called Umbraco, and in the bindings properties, I have an entry for port 80, all unassigned, with a host name of `localumbraco.net`.  However, if I try and browse this host name, I get a `Server not found` error in the browser.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

What have you done for DNS?

Simplest method: edit your HOSTS file in C:\windows\system32\etc\drivers\ and point localumbraco.net to localhost.

More robust method (if you want others on your network to view your website): add an entry in your local DNS server.

Comment: Aah, that's where it is (actually windows\system32\drivers\etc, but I haven't edited a hosts file for years, and couldn't find it, so I thought maybe things had changed.  I'm just doing this for personal dev, so I'll leave DNS out of it for now.